# Invalid Syntax when defining variable

Tags: python

I get invalid syntax error message when trying to define loggedin1 in the code below
anyone able to tell me why? yes im new to coding. I haven't defined it anywhere else so I dont know what is wrong.

```
##login function##
loggedin1 = False
loggedin2 = False
while loggedin1 == False:
    username = input("what is your username? ")
    if username == "user1" or username == "user2" or \ # '\' carries over code
       username == "user3" or username == "user4":     # to the next line
        password = input("what is your password? ")
        if password == "123456789":
            loggedin1 = True
            player1 = username
            print("player 1 successfully logged in")
        else:
            print("incorrect password, please try again")
    else:
        print("invalid username, please try again")
while loggedin2 == False:
    username = input("what is your username? ")
    if username == "user1" or username == "user2" or \
       username == "user3" or username == "user4":
        password = input("what is your password? ")
        if password == "123456789":
            loggedin2 = True
            player2 = username
        else:
            print("incorrect password, please try again")
    else:
        print("invalid username, please try again")
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you checked indentation?

Comment: Show the full error traceback. you also should check if the error derives from the last code line above the `##login function##` (e.g. missing parentheses)

Comment: @Carsten incorrect indentation should lead to an `IndentationError` not a `SyntaxError`

Comment: ah, Yep Chris i had a print line above and missed parentheses thanks!

Comment: You need to make a [mre]

Answer (score -1):

just for fun I refactored your code, regards!

```
valid_usernames = ["user1","user2","user3","user4"]
valid_password = "123456789"

def login_function():
    player1 = login_player("player 1")
    player2 = login_player("player 2")


def login_player(player):
    loggedin = False
    while loggedin == False:
        username = input("what is your username? ")
        loggedin = try_loggin(username, player)

    return username


def try_loggin(username, player):
    if username in valid_usernames:
        password = input("what is your password? ")
        if password == valid_password:
            print(player + " successfully logged in")
            return True
        else:
            print("incorrect password, please try again")
    else:
        print("invalid username, please try again")

    return False

if __name__== "__main__":
    login_function()
```

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, I think that the original function was a very first approach, with lots of duplicate code, so I was bored and I suggest a more readable and reusable version (in my opinion). Problem was solved in comments before I post my answer. So my question to you is: what's your problem? Invest more time contributing positively and less banning people, you'll become a hapier being